# How to keep Bing Maps Image Media from scaling with zoom

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps to make some kind of editor. One of the things the editor needs to do as add an Image to the map and have it not scale. I can add the image with out any problem but I cant seem to keep it from scaling when you change your zoom level. Is there a way to set the scale to be fixed when you create the image and add it to the map. I really want to avoid always changing the scale of the image when the zoom level changes as there can be ton of these images on the map.
I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581713/bing-maps-silverlight-control-pushpin-scaling-problems) but that did not seem to fix my problem.

here is the code I am using so far:

```
MapLayer imageLayer = new MapLayer();

Image image = new Image();
image.Height = 150;
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("../../triangle.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
myBitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 150;
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
image.Source = myBitmapImage;
image.Opacity = 0.6;
image.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;

//The map location to place the image at
Location location = new Location() { Latitude = 37.8197222222222, Longitude = -122.478611111111};
//Center the image around the location specified
PositionOrigin position = PositionOrigin.Center;

imageLayer.AddChild(image, location, position);
MapWithPolygon.Children.Add(imageLayer);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided won't scale the image when zooming. It's possible that it might look slightly scaled due to the background changing but the physical pixel size of the image will not change. The image will only scale if you bounded it to a LocationRect instead of a location.